# Resize font size with a change in height by autolayout on a textfield

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, autolayout

I have a UITextField that can be resized with autolayout. How can I make the font size automatically smaller when the textfield height gets smaller than the font?

Thanks

Comment: The question is why would you want the height of the text field to change its size? Normally you only change its width.

Comment: I have rigged the textfield to change height with the screen size with autolayout. It would be nice if the font scaled as well...

Comment: I found this [developer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/dividingResponsibility.html) stating *".. a text field calls invalidateIntrinsicContentSize if the string value changes."* It may help you?

Answer (score 1):

I wish I could figure out how to leave comments like other's do, without making it an answer.

Anyway, this seems to be something pretty fundamental to the design of iOS, there just does not seem to be any acknowledgment of this kind of thing, the entire design of the libraries/objects/properties seems to think you'd only ever want to change the font size, based on the width, but this seems entirely arbitrary to me.  With auto layout, it seems like just an unfortunate carry over from springs and struts that needs to be fixed.

As a work-around, you could create some constraints to link the width of the label to the height, by some proportion, so that the height change caused the width to also change, and thus force the font to change.

I am trying to solve the same problem.

These constraints will have to be created in code, as far as I can tell.

Comment: You will be able to leave comments when you have 50 reputation.  See [privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges).

Comment: That could work if there's a fixed ratio between width and height. To this to happen the text and font must always be the same. So it will not work on a multilanguage app or if apple changes something on iOS.